# How to make window forms to be transperent?

Tags: winforms, timer, mouseevent, transparency, keyboard-events

I would like to achieve next scenario with my winform application :

when the application is being launched it stays on the desktop. in case and user didn't use the application for a while for examp 1min, i would like it to lose it it's transparency (the main form's transparency reduced to half)

in case and the application was used (focus, mouse hovering...) once again , the main form's transparency value is set back to 100%.

so where actually i need to start ?

i assume that i need to use a timer in different thread which fire some event in case and it's reach 1 min, but the question here , how (and which) i would listen to from's events in different thread (the one i use for the timer)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forms have an opacity value:

```
form1.Opacity = 0.5;
```

You can tap into the [Application Idle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx) event to start your timeout timer.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars says there is the `Opacity` property on the form.

To set the opacity to a half when the form is inactive you'll need to handle the `Deactivated` or the [Application.Idle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx) event. In this start a timer that will send a message back to the form (on the UI thread) to actually set the value.

```
private void Form_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.inactiveTimer = new Timer();
    this.inactiveTimer.Interval = 1000;
    this.inactiveTimer.Tick += this.InactiveTimer_Tick;
    // Start timer
    this.inactiveTimer.Start();
}

private void InactiveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is being handled on the UI thread
    this.Opacity = 0.5;
    this.inactiveTimer.Stop();
}
```

If you want the form to gradually gain transparency then set the timer interval to a smaller amount (say 100 ms) and reduce the transparency by steps on each tick. Then when the opacity reaches 0.5 stop the timer then.

The `Activated` event is fired when the form becomes active again:

```
private void Form_Activate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 1.0;
    // Stop the timer for the cases where the user reactivates the app
    this.inactiveTimer.Stop();
}
```

There are other events like `SizeChanged` that you might need to trap to ensure that the opacity is set back to 1 correctly (this is fired when the form is restored from being minimised) and `ResizeEnd`.